# How refresh / update ng2 smart table when a row is edited Angular7

Tags: angular7, refresh, ng2-smart-table

I need to update ng2 smart table after editing a row. Is there a method to refresh the array of objects?

Comment: Are you using DataSouce?
Are you using event for edit with external mode?

Answer (score 0):

if your are using source, you can use
this.source.refresh();